# Problema com routerLink no angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
          <h6 class="text-center">
            Do not have an account yet?
            <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/signup']">Sign up now!</a>
          </h6>
        </div>
```

Fiz algumas pesquisas, mas não encontrei nada que resolvesse.

Eu já importei o `RouterModule` e `Routes` em meu arquivo `app-routing.module.ts`: `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`

E esse arquivo, estou importando no meu `app.module.ts`.

Esta funcionando perfeitamente, e do anda esta gerando o erro quando eu uso a propertyBinding do RouterLink.

Comment: #Tutorial [Suporte](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) tem vários objetos de suporte nesse tutorial tanto router, formbuild você cadastrou o router no constructor?

Comment: poste seu código... e mais fácil identificar o erro

Comment: Só estou chamando o routerLink dentro de uma tag <a>.
Não tem nada relacionando a formulário....
Também não instanciei o Router no contrutor

Comment: Da uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317044/) do SOen

Comment: Eu já vi... não é isso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importa o RouterModule no modulo que vc declara seu componente e não so no app module.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado!